# Why my RelativeLayout is not shown when calling AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-view, android-relativelayout

I have an issue in my Android app. The view is normally loaded when the AsyncTask is commented.
When, I uncomment it, the activity doesn't show / load the view. The Activity is empty...

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:indeterminate="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Java

```
public class ActivitySplash extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

        new AsyncDownloadJson(this).execute("https://my-api-url.com").get();

    }
}
```

Can you explain to me why ?
Thanks.

Comment: You have to show your view in the onPostExecute of Async Task.

Comment: How does your `AsyncDownloadJson` look like and don't call `get()` on it or else your User Interface Thread will freeze.

Comment: Without the `get()` it will only launch the AsyncTask without showing the UI. How to show the view and wait the AsyncTask result ?

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Asynctask.get()` in main thread, so your main thread is freezing.

You should simply call `new AsyncDownloadJson(this).execute("https://my-api-url.com");` and update your GUI in `onPostExecute(Result)`.

For more details read [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)